# Why is StringValues assignable to String

Tags: c#

I don't understand why the following compiles:

```
StringValues sv = httpContext.Request.Query["param"];
string s = sv;
```

My knowledge says that `a` is assignable to `b` only if `a` is of type `b` or `a` extends/implements `b`. But looking at the docs it doesn't look like `StringValues` extends `string` (`string` is a sealed class, therefore it shouldn't be even possible).

So I assume this is some implicit conversion going on here, but I can't find any info on it.

Comment: In fact, the cases you name are just two particular instances of [implicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-conversions), there are many more.

Comment: Your belief that assignability and type derivation are the same thing is very wrong, so stop believing that *right now*. `int` is not derived from `double` but `int` is assignable to `double`. `Func<string>` is not derived from `Func<object>` but is assignable. `string[]` is not derived from `object[]` but (unfortunately) is assignable. `int` is not derived from `int?` but is assignable.  I could go on for some time, but you get the point. I recommend that you read the specification if you wish to know the actual rules for assignment compatibility.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a user-defined implicit conversion to `string`:

[Source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/StringValues.cs,71)

```
public static implicit operator string (StringValues values)
{
    return values.GetStringValue();
}
```

See [User-defined conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).

The [MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues.op_implicit?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Primitives_StringValues_op_Implicit_Microsoft_Extensions_Primitives_StringValues__System_String) aren't very clear, but they're there if you know where to look.

Comment: Almost correct, it's a different implicit operator: public static implicit operator string (StringValues values).  The one in the answer converts a string to a StringValues object, but the SO asks the opposite.

Comment: And here is API reference of implicit operator for `StringValues` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues.op_implicit?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Primitives_StringValues_op_Implicit_Microsoft_Extensions_Primitives_StringValues__System_String

Comment: @johey D'oh, read the question too quickly. Corrected, thanks

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that the types `StringValues` and `String` are not in any way related on the class diagrams (strings being marked sealed, StringValues being a struct), that only means Polymorphy can not affect them there.

There are rare cases where there are implicit, prewritten converters between two types. Those are admittedly a relatively rare sight, so it is understandable if you do not expect one.

Practice taught us that overely agressive implicit conversions causes issues. .NET and C# are intentionally strongly typed. So accordingly, they are very conservative with implicit conversions. Which result in people not expecting them, much like the Spanish inquisition.

While strong typification has it's own downsides, personally, I prefer it. See the PHP and JavaScript examples of [this comic](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/) for weak typisation in action. Hint: JavaScript does the wrong thing in both cases. One just happens to have the right result.